# Como funciona o G1 (Garbage First Collector)?

Tags: java, desempenho, gerenciamento-de-memória, jvm, garbage-collector

No [JEP-248](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/248) vem se discutindo a definição do G1 ([Garbage First Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/G1.html)) como o Garbage Collector padrão no [Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/). Nesse período, venho ouvindo muitas citações sobre o G1, mas muito pouco material tem detalhes mais profundos ou comparações como por exemplo, com o [CMS (Concurrent Mark and Sweep)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html), o qual seria hoje o GC *"padrão"* em aplicações em produção com requerimentos mínimos de performance.

Visto que o gerenciamento de memória automático provido pela **JVM** é um dos pontos cruciais da plataforma, gostaria de uma visão mais profunda do porquê (prós e contras) da adoção desse novo garbage collector, além de um paralelo com as implementações existentes.

Comment: Vou acompanhar essa pergunta +1

Comment: É sequer possível responder isso em se tratando de um produto de código-fonte fechado?

O "tchan" desse G1 parece ser a subdivisão da memória em blocos, e a priorização em fazer GC nos blocos quase vazios, inclusive movendo objetos para fora do bloco a fim de liberá-lo. Isso evita um problema típico de sistemas com GC: usar um caminhão de memória, com objetos ocupando esta memória muito esparsamente.

Detalhes de como isso é realmente implementado, só olhando o código, e certamente o G1 vai ter desempenho pior em cargas específicas (embora deva ser melhor no caso médio, senão não iam usar.)

Comment: Ainda acho que existe espaço razoavel para melhorias nas respostas, eu tenho um conhecimento razoavel do G1 ele já vem sendo implementado/usado desde 2009. Vou ver se complemento a resposta antes de definir como correta. Obrigado pela recompensa @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Regis, prega fogo aí. Falta uma hora pra acabar a recompensa.

Comment: Não tenho uma resposta, mas [essa referência](http://www.infoq.com/articles/G1-One-Garbage-Collector-To-Rule-Them-All) (em inglês) parece descrever razoavelmente bem o processo. Se tivesse visto a pergunta antes, podia arriscar uma tradução, mas de todo modo à primeira vista creio que a [resposta do Daniel](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83514/215) toca em todos os pontos importantes - ainda que sem entrar muito em detalhe (na minha interpretação, o GC do Java já é generacional há bastante tempo, então não é essa a novidade; o que melhorou, me parece, foi só a implementação mesmo).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Os coletores de lixo (Garbage Collector) clássicos funcionam mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

1. Eles paralisam a execução do aplicativo;
2. Eles escaneiam **toda** a memória do aplicativo, para identificar quais objetos não podem mais ser acessados, e os liberam da memória;
3. Eles resumem a execução do aplicativo;

Essa paralisação é um problema para grandes aplicativos que precisam ser altamente responsivos, como o Facebook por exemplo, pois quanto mais memória o aplicativo usa, maior o tempo de paralisação e menor a responsividade do aplicativo.

O coletor atual da JVM, o Concurrent Mark and Sweep (CMS), executa parte do scan e da liberação de memória concorrentemente com a execução da aplicação (daí o nome), para tentar reduzir o tempo de paralisação. Isso reduz o problema mas não o resolve.

O Garbage First Collector (G1C) resolve esse problema utilizando algumas técnicas:

- Ele escaneia a memória sem paralisar a execução do aplicativo.
- Ele divide a memória em blocos para permitir coletas parciais.
- Ele permite a configuração de um tempo limite de paralisação para a coleta de lixo.
- Ele estima quantos blocos de memória ele consegue coletar, dentro do tempo limite, usando dados das coletas anteriores.
- Ele prioriza a coleta dos blocos com mais lixo.
- Ele coleta usando evacuação, ou seja: ele pega um bloco, move o que não é lixo para outro bloco e libera o primeiro bloco inteiro.

Comment: seria interessando você colocar as fontes da sua resposta, para termos uma versão mais detalhada da sua resposta.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não tenho nenhuma outra fonte além dos links da pergunta e dos meus conhecimentos sobre o funcionamento de coletores de memória em geral.

Comment: Só um detalhe: o CMS não paralisa uma única vez para fazer o escaneamento e coleta - ele paralisa uma vez (*mark*) para identificar os objetos "vivos" e depois paralisa outra vez (*remark*) para pegar o que faltou. A coleta em si é paralela à execução do aplicativo, sem mais pausas (daí o *"concurrent"* no nome - se pausasse também na coleta, seria simplesmente *"mark and sweep"*...). Mais detalhes [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Alterei a resposta para incluir essa informação.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor explicação sobre G1 em relação ao CMS:
[Getting Started with the G1 Garbage Collector](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/index.html)

O texto é um pouco extenso (não pretendo fazer a tradução inteira), mas em resumo:

- Como o heap é organizado no **CMS** e no **G1** (*G1 Operational Overview*)
- Tipos de heap: geração permanente, velha geração e nova geração (*G1 Operational Overview*)
- Como a coleta ocorre no **CMS** (*Reviewing Generational GC and CMS*)
- Como a coleta da **nova** geração ocorre no **G1** (*The G1 Garbage Collector Step by Step*)
- Como a coleta da **velha** geração ocorre no **G1** (*G1 Old Generation Collection Step by Step*)